# applicationset is failing with error "cannot find the destination cluster" , even though the cluster exsist in my ArgoCD Clusters List

Tags: devops, argocd, argo, gitops

I added 4 K8s clusters in my ArgoCD (within same network) in my ArgoCD Clusters Setup and when I am creating a new applicationset with one of the clusters, it's failing with below error:

```
> $ argocd appset list
> 
> NAME NAMESPACE PROJECT SYNCPOLICY CONDITIONS REPO PATH TARGET
> 
> my-applicationset argocd default nil [{ErrorOccurred application
> destination spec is invalid: unable to find destination server: there
> are no clusters with this name: https://my.k8s.server:8443 2023-08-14
> 16:14:39 -0400 EDT True ApplicationValidationError}
> {ParametersGenerated Successfully generated parameters for all
> Applications 2023-08-14 16:14:39 -0400 EDT True ParametersGenerated}]
> https://my.github.reo.git {{path}} HEAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have mixed the usage of cluster address and cluster name.

- `server` is to be used with a cluster address
- `name` is to be used with a cluster name

Comment: Yes, I figured out the mistake I made. Facepalm to that.

Comment: Done. I marked it as the answer.